# What does the notation $p/|p|$ mean in topology?

Tags: general-topology, notation

What does the notation $p/|p|$ mean in topology? I guess it's associated with boundary/restriction of a map, but don't know how it is strictly defined...

Comment: What is $p$? In what context have you seen this notation? For me this could be a non-zero point $p$ in $\Bbb R^n$, divided by its norm $\|p\|$.

Comment: Guillemin Pollack , page 81. Here is a link: http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math260s10/old/difftopGP.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It just refers to the function $f(x)=p(x)/\|p(x)\|$, where the $\|\cdot \|$ term is the Euclidean norm, and $p$ has codomain $\Bbb R^n$. This is well defined and smooth if $p$ is never zero, and has image on the unit sphere.